# Connecting a ' local network ' python chatroom to the ' internet '

Tags: python, sockets, ip, chat, portforwarding

so i tried to make a simple chat room with python 3.8 , with a simple twist that instead of having one server and tow client connecting to that server , the conversation goes on between a client and the server it self , the code worked completely as intended on a single machine and also on tow different devices on a local network ( both connected to the same router and modem ) , but when i tried to access it on a different device **out of the local network** , client could not connect to the server , here is my code for the **server side** :

```
import socket
import threading

FORMAT = "utf-8"
PORT = 9999
HOST_IP = '192.168.1.56'
print("[SERVER STARTING]")
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST_IP, PORT))
server.listen()


def accepting():
    global connection
    print('[WAITING FOR CONNECTION ... ]')
    while True:
        connection, address = server.accept()
        print(f'[NEW CONNECTION] {address} Connected to the server ')
        connection.send(f"[SERVER] Welcome to {HOST_IP}".encode(FORMAT))
def receiving():
    global connection
    while True:
        try:
            msg = connection.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
            if len(msg) == 0:
                pass
            else:
                print('[CLIENT] ' + msg)
        except:
            pass
def sending():
    global connection
    while True:
        try:
            server_msg = input("> ")
            connection.send(server_msg.encode(FORMAT))
        except:
            pass
receiving_th = threading.Thread(target=receiving)
accepting_th = threading.Thread(target=accepting)
sending_th = threading.Thread(target=sending)
accepting_th.start()
receiving_th.start()
sending_th.start()
```

i tried changing the HOST_IP on line 6 to all of the following :

```
HOST_IP = ''
HOST_IP = '0.0.0.0'
HOST_IP = '127.0.0.1'
```

neither of them worked . i also tried putting my **Public IP address** but the following error poped up :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\PrivateMssg1.0\Server.py", line 9, in <module>
    server.bind((HOST_IP, PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

on the **client side** , here is my code :

```
import socket
import threading

FORMAT = "utf-8"
PORT = 9999
HOST_IP = "192.168.1.56"
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST_IP, PORT))
msg = client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
print(msg)



def receiving():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT)
            print('[SERVER] ' + msg)
        except:
            pass
def sending():
    while True:
        try:
            client_msg = input("> ")
            client.send(client_msg.encode(FORMAT))
        except:
            pass
receiving_th = threading.Thread(target=receiving)
sending_th = threading.Thread(target=sending)
receiving_th.start()
sending_th.start()
```

i tried my Public IP address here on line 6 `HOST_IP = "my public IP"`  as well but it didnt work .
i researched about 2 days and tried disabling my **PC s firewall** and **my router firewall** but that didnt work either .
i also tried **opening port 9999 on my pc** and also **Port Forwarding** port 9999 on my router to my local ip 196.168.1.56 . i tried restarting my router and my pc . but none of them worked .  i dont think my code is causing it to not connect because it worked fine on a local network . can anyone help me out ?
and can someone try ,y code on their setup ? because the problem might be with my router not port forwarding correctly .

Comment: 0.0.0.0 should work, but you need to make sure the remote client knows your (router's) public IP address, and that your ISP allows external inbound access to that address.

Comment: Python 3.0 is severely buggy and out of date; are you _really_ using a version from 2008!?

Comment: binding to 192.168.1.56, configuring the firewall(s) to allow inbound port 9999 connections to your python program,  **and** port forwarding port 9999 to this address should work. Configuring firewalls and router port forwarding is going to be very specific to your setup.

Comment: ive tried adding an inbound rule for port 9999 in my PCs firewall but that didnt solve the problem , ive also tried port forwarding 9999 and ive tried different ports but neither worked out

Comment: can this problem be caused by using a DNS other than the default DNS ?

Comment: you should use AF_INET6 and then put your public ip address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was with my public IP , you need a static public IP to be able to accept inbound request, it worked fine on a linux based server .