# requesting access to the router out side of the local network with a dynamic ip

Tags: networking, ip, router, static-ip-address, dynamic-ip

do you need to have a static IP ( Public ip ) to be able to send requests to your router ? or a dynamic ip works as well ? ive been trying to access my router out side of the local network and ive tried everything but it just does not work , i have a dynamic IP .

Answer (score 1):

No, a static IP is not needed, however if using a dynamic IP to connect, you always need to know the current IP address, as it usually changes daily (depending on where you live). You can use a dynamic dns service, that repeatendly updates your domain to forward to your dynamic IP, which is much more comftable than always looking up your current IP.

Addressing your connection problem:
When accessing your network from outside, you need to forward a port to a device in your local network. Accessing the router directly from outside is not possible for most routers, as it would be pretty insecure. However, you can forward a port to a host in your network, connect to it and access the router from there.

Pinging the router from outside will also not work on most routers, as most firewalls block ping from outside by default

Comment: ive tried port forwarding and updating the ip address but neither worked out , ive posted my situation fully at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68564098/connecting-a-local-network-python-chatroom-to-the-internet

Comment: you can check if the port is open and accepting tcp connections with this tool: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ Also try to use port 80, as some providers block certain ports. Port 80 should be working as its the default http port.

Comment: i checked both port 80 and other known ports and port 9999 with i port forwarded , all of the were CLOSED!!?? how ?